# Error in quick start guide

Tags: csv, encog

I'm new to encog, and I recently read the "Quick Start Guide"

However I found a things that I consider an error, can you confirm this?
In the final "chapter", "Using Encog for Time Series", the output is printed in the console using this code:

```
while (csv.next() && stopAfter > 0) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            line[0] = csv.get(2);// ssn
            line[1] = csv.get(3);// dev
            helper.normalizeInputVector(line, slice, false);

            // enough data to build a full window?
            if (window.isReady()) {
                window.copyWindow(input.getData(), 0);
                String correct = csv.get(2); // trying to predict SSN.
                MLData output = bestMethod.compute(input);
                String predicted = helper
                        .denormalizeOutputVectorToString(output)[0];

                result.append(Arrays.toString(line));
                result.append(" -> predicted: ");
                result.append(predicted);
                result.append("(correct: ");
                result.append(correct);
                result.append(")");
```

The wrong I think it is wrong, is the "correct" variable: since it is predicting the SSN value from the CSV, it is right to read it using csv.get(2), but it should be invoked on time "t+1". In this code it is evaluated equals to SSN at time t

The output shows this too:

[9.4, 9.1] -> predicted: 16.576461298905144(correct: 9.4)
here it is clear that "correct" value is the same as input.

Am I missing anything?

thanks

A.